# Laravel error: Missing required parameter for [Route: bodmembers.show] [URI: adminpanel/bodmembers/{bodmember}] [Missing parameter: bodmember]

Tags: php, routes, laravel-9

i keep getting this error

Missing required parameter for [Route: bodmembers.show] [URI: adminpanel/bodmembers/{bodmember}] [Missing parameter: bodmember].

https://flareapp.io/share/LPdLQgQP#F58

**my index View**

```
<a href="{{route('bodmembers.show', ['BODMember' => $BODMember['id']]) }}">Edit Info</a>
```

**my controller**

```
public function show(BODMember $BODMember)
    {
      
        return view('adminpanel.bodmembers.item_BODMember', [
            'BODMember' => $BODMember
        ]);


    }
```

**my routes**

```
Route::resource('adminpanel/bodmembers', BODMembersController::class);
```

Im expecting to view the index all the list om BOD members and when i click the edit info, it will go to the certain view and display the certain item

Im following youtube tutorial and im stuck to this error
https://youtu.be/AGE3wRKljkw?t=5313

this is the github repo of the yt tutorial
https://github.com/tutsplus/get-started-with-laravel-8.git

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongs on model binding structure. However, if you want to list all data, then you should change your controller before:

```php
public function show(BODMember $BODMember)
{
    return view('adminpanel.bodmembers.item_BODMember', [
        'BODMember' => $BODMember->get()
    ]);
}
```

Instead of get all data, if you want to show single data in view, then you must pass parameter from route:

```php
Route::get('adminpanel/bodmembers/{member}', [BODMembersController::class,'show']);
```

And to catch it from controller:

```php
public function show(BODMember $member)
{
    return view('adminpanel.bodmembers.item_BODMember', [
        'BODMember' => $member
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I still have the error, can you give me clear instruction

Comment: Do you want to show single item or all items ?